# Collision not working in 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made 2D wall in Unity, but my character can walk through it. What's wrong? My character has Rigibody2D and BoxCollider2D, wall has box collider.
Code of character movement:

```
Vector2 moveVec = new Vector2(CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal"),CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    moveVec = moveVec * moveForce;
    transform.Translate (moveVec);
```

Comment: Does your character have a BoxCollider2D (note the 2D at the end). Same for your wall.

Comment: Yes, it has BoxCollider2D

Comment: try to use rigidbody.MovePosition instead of transform.Translate. Also check the collision mask and object layers

Comment: What if you add a Rigidbody2D on your wall?

Comment: still nothing happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My character has Rigibody2D and BoxCollider

If you use `Rigibody2D`, you must also use `BoxCollider2D` not `BoxCollider`. Make sure the wall has it's `BoxCollider2D` too.

No collision when `transform.Translate` or `transform.position` is used to move an Object. If your GameObject has Rigidbody2D 
 attached to it, then it must be moved with `Rigidbody2D.velocity`, `Rigidbody2D.AddForce`(`Rigidbody2D.AddXXX`) or `Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`.

It is better to do this particular thing in the `FixedUpdate()` function. Also, I think `GetAxisRaw` should be used instead of  `GetAxis` so that the player will stop *immediately* the key/finger is released.

```
public float speed = 2f;
Rigidbody2D rg2d;

void Start()
{
    rg2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector2 tempVect = new Vector2(h, v);
    tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    rg2d.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + tempVect);
}
```

You can always decrease/increase the speed if it moves too fast/slow.

Comment: You should use Time.fixedDeltaTime;

Comment: @JuanBayonaBeriso That's right. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: thanks. what's the difference between update and fixedupdate?

Comment: + I don't know what's wrong, but no matter what's value of speed, the object moves with the same speed

Comment: [fixedDeltaTime vs deltaTime](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/713217/exact-difference-between-fixeddeltatime-and-deltat.html)

Comment: The `speed` variable is a `public` variable which means that once it is created in your script, it remains the-same default value (2) unless you change it by assigning it again **in a function** with `speed = yourNewValue`. You have two options: Change it from the Editor, or make it `private` then you can change it's default value `public float speed = 1f;`

Comment: Ok, I know, I didn't set mass. But I want my character to be only kinematic and can't walk through wall, is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141974/discussion-between-sleeper-and-programmer).

Comment: I am away from my computer at this moment and will be back in hours. You can always create new question if the problem is totally different. When I come back I will see if I can help.